# Relacionar tablas mysql con php

Tags: mysql, sql

necesito crear un código que me asocio la información de 2 tablas, en una tengo la id del grupo y la de cada participante pero en la otra únicamente tengo la del participante, el problema es que necesito sacar la información de ambas tablas basándome en la id del grupo

Comment: Tu pregunta no se entiende del todo. ¿Podrías por favor poner la estructura de las tablas que estás manejando, con algunos datos de ejemplo, la consulta en la que tienes dificultades, los resultados que obtienes y los resultados que esperas obtener? Sospecho que meter un ID de grupo dentro de la tabla usuario podría ser un error de diseño, a no ser que cada usuario deba pertenecer a un solo grupo.

Comment: Tabla1: ID(usuario) ID(grupo) Nombre Apellidos  Tabla 2: ID(usuario) Horario Información.  Necesito lanzar un select con la ID del grupo y obtener nombre, apellidos, horario e informacion de todos lo usuarios pertenecientes a ese grupo. Cada usuario pertenece unicamente a un solo grupo. Gracias

Comment: Tienes que relacionarlo por el campo Tabla1.Id == Tabla2.Id, así sacas la información de los usuarios del grupo 43

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Me parece entender que quieres algo así:

```
SELECT * FROM tabla2 WHERE id_usuario IN (
    SELECT id_usuario FROM tabla1 WHERE id_grupo=43
  );
```

Para un dataset como este:

```
CREATE TABLE tabla1(
  id_grupo int,
  id_usuario int,
  nombre varchar(15),
  apellidos varchar(31)
  );
CREATE TABLE tabla2(
  id_usuario int,
  horario varchar(15),
  info varchar(31)
  );
INSERT INTO tabla1 (id_grupo, id_usuario, nombre, apellidos) VALUES
  (1,1,'Pedro','Delgado'),
  (43,2,'Miguel','Induráin'),
  (43,3,'Ramiro','Alonso'),
  (2,4,'Jose','Méndez');
INSERT INTO tabla2 (id_usuario, horario, info) VALUES
  (1,'Matutino','Pedro Delgado'),
  (2,'Vespertino','Miguelón'),
  (3,'Nocturno','Ramiro'),
  (4,'Nocturno','Méndez');
```

Del que esperas un resultado así:

> ```
> 2 Vespertino  Miguelón
> 3 Nocturno    Ramiro
> ```

Por favor, confírmame si es así e indícame qué dudas te surgen, para detallarte lo que necesites de la consulta.

La solución que plantea @RubénEspada con un `JOIN` es igualmente válida:

```
SELECT * FROM (
    SELECT * FROM tabla1 WHERE id_grupo=43
  ) c1 JOIN tabla2 USING(id_usuario);
```

Así como:

```
SELECT * FROM tabla1 JOIN tabla2 USING(id_usuario)
  WHERE id_grupo=43;
```

La ventaja de estas últimas es que muestran información de ambas tablas:

> ```
> 2 43  Miguel  Induráin    Vespertino  Miguelón
> 3 43  Ramiro  Alonso  Nocturno    Ramiro
> ```

Comment: Buenas, he modificado la pregunta, a ver si pudiera decirme donde esta el error. Muchas gracias

Comment: Ante todo, bienvenido a Stackoverflow. Como la pregunta que planteas ahora es diferente a la anterior, deberías valorar ésta (cuando consideres que está correctamente respondida), y abrir una nueva. Encantado de que me pases el enlace de la nueva para echarle un vistazo. Sí te ruego que, al igual que he hecho yo, envíes el dataset que has utilizado y lo que esperas obtener de esos datos de prueba.

Comment: Buenas, te comparto en enlace de la nueva pregunta, la he realizado de la forma más clara posible, espero que se comprenda bien. Este es el enlace: https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/318758/relacionar-tablas-mysql-con-php-y-enviar-la-respuesta-a-otra-base-de-datos Muchas gracias

Comment: ¿Es posible que dejes la pregunta como estaba originalmente para que la respuesta sea coherente con ésta? Recuerda que el fin último de stackoverflow es dejar constancia de las dudas para otros miembros de la comunidad con preguntas similares a la que tenías inicialmente

Comment: La dejaré como estaba, muchas gracias