# Relacionar tablas mysql con php y enviar la respuesta a otra base de datos

Tags: php, mysql

He creado el siguiente código, primero extraigo de la tabla "tournament" la ID de la competición basándome en el código introducido en un formulario previamente.

```
$codigo = $_GET['s_competition_code'];

        $conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "ianseo", "ianseo", "ianseo");

        $sql1 = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM tournament WHERE ToCode= '$codigo'") or die ("Error1: $sql1");
        $mostrar = mysqli_fetch_all($sql1,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        foreach($mostrar as $campo=>$t);

        $localid = $t['ToId'];
```

Después, en la segunda consulta pretendo extraer de la tabla entries el nombre y apellidos del participante y de la tabla qualifications extraigo la diana (QuTarget) y la puntuacion (QuScore). Para extraer estos datos me baso en que ambas tablas comparten una misma id para cada participante, en el caso de la primera tabla (entries) en campo se llama EnId y en el caso de la segunda (qualifications) se llama QuID, el problema es que únicamente quiero extraer los datos que tengan como ID de la competición la $localid extraída anteriormente. Esta id solo esta en la tabla entries.

```
       $sql2 = mysqli_query($conn,"SELECT * FROM entries JOIN qualifications USING(QuId) WHERE EnTournament=$localid") or die ("Error2: $sql2");
        $mostrar2 = mysqli_fetch_all($sql2,MYSQLI_ASSOC);
        foreach($mostrar2 as $campo=>$s);   

        $conn1 = mysqli_connect("server", "user", "pass", "db");

        if (!$conn1) {
              die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
        }
```

Por último, lo que hago es enviar estos datos a la base de datos de una web.

```
mysqli_query($conn1,"DELETE FROM `asirio_Resultados`.`clasificacion` WHERE `clasificacion`.`code` = '$codigo'");
        foreach($mostrar2 as $campo=>$r)
            mysqli_query($conn1,"
                INSERT INTO clasificacion (ID, code, Nombre, Apellidos, DianaN, Puntuacion)
                    VALUES ('".$r['EnId']."', '".$codigo."', '".$r['EnName']."', '".$r['EnFirstName']."', '".$r['QuTarget']."', '".$r['QuScore']."')");
```

He probado esto pero me da error. 
El dataset es el siguiente:

```
CREATE TABLE entries(
  EnTournament int,
  EnID int,
  Nombre varchar(15),
  Apellidos varchar(31)
  );
CREATE TABLE qualifications (
  QuId int,
  QuTarget varchar(15),
  QuScore int
  );
CREATE TABLE tournament(
  ToId int,
  Name varchar(15),
  ToCode varchar(15)
  );
INSERT INTO entries(ToId, EnId, nombre, apellidos) VALUES
  (123,22900,'Pedro','Delgado'),
  (123,22901,'Miguel','Induráin'),
  (123,22902,'Ramiro','Alonso'),
  (124,22903,'Jose','Méndez');
INSERT INTO qualifications (QuId, QuTarget, QuScore) VALUES
  (22900,'1A','578'),
  (22901,'1B','550'),
  (22902,'2A','580'),
  (22903,'2B','567'),
```

Al final lo que necesitaría obtener es lo siguiente (Unicamente los participantes de la competición 123 por ejemplo) :

```
123 22900 1A 578 Pedro Delgado
123 22901 1B 578 Miguel Indurain
123 22902 2A 578 Ramiro Alonso
```

Pero esta información no tendría que mostrarse en pantalla, tendría que enviarse a otra base de datos alojada en un servidor.

Muchísimas gracias y un saludo.

Comment: Por favor, añade algún dato para hacer las pruebas y qué esperas obtener a partir de esos datos. Ya sabes: INSERT INTO ...

Comment: Cuál es el específicamente el error (mensaje que se te presenta)?, sin este dato es muy difícil ayudar

Comment: Falta la tabla qualifications y terminas los foreach con punto y coma (;). Finalmente, accedes a otra base de datos... ¿Qué error obtienes?

Comment: He modificado la pregunta añadiendo lo que me pediste, simplemente obtengo "error:", que supongo que vendrá de la segunda consulta

Comment: Además no recibo nada en la base de datos de la web

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ese error te aparece porque, probablemente y como te ha pasado al formular la pregunta, aún no hayas definido la tabla `tournament`. Por favor, modifica la pregunta añadiendo esta tabla para que podamos continuar depurando tu código.

Para que el error sea algo más específico, te propongo que almacenes tu query en una variable intermedia `$sql` y así podrás tener más pistas sobre la causa del error.

```
<?php 
$codigo = $_GET['s_competition_code'];

$conn = mysqli_connect("localhost", "root", "", "stackoverflow");

$sql="SELECT * FROM tournament WHERE ToCode= '$codigo'";
$sql1 = mysqli_query($conn,$sql) or die ("Error: $sql");
```

Aunque, hasta que no envíes es tabla aún no pueda comprobarlo, veo que intentas conectar dos tablas por un campo con nombre diferentes:

```
SELECT * FROM entries JOIN qualifications
    USING(QuId) WHERE EnTournament=$localid
```

Para realizar esa conexión con éxito deberías utilizar `ON` en vez de `USING` y utilizar el campo `ToId` que es en el que guardas el nombre de la competición. `EnTournament` no aparece en ninguna de las tablas que nos envías e intentas combinar:

```
SELECT * FROM entries JOIN qualifications
    ON QuId=EnId WHERE ToId=$localid;
```

Da la sensación de que estás confundiendo dos bases de datos o tablas diferentes, imprime el esquema y tenlo delante cuando codifiques las consultas, verás cómo te resulta mucho más fácil.

Comment: Buenas, la tabla tournament existe y la qualifications y entries también, el problema no es que estén creadas las tablas ya que lo que estoy haciendo es una modificación de un programa ya existente y todas estas tablas están ya creadas, puede ser otra cosa?

Comment: Puede que el problema sea que en una tabla la id es QuId y en otra Enid y para unir las tablas solo estoy poniendo una de las dos Id?

Comment: A eso me refería: pásanos la tabla `tournament` para que podamos replicar el fallo y hazte un esquema con los campos de cada tabla. Ya casi lo tienes

Comment: Buenas, he modificado la pregunta añadiendo la tabla tournament, pero al ejecutar el código recibo "Error2:" por lo que imagino que el error estará en la segunda consulta, no se si será en el join de la tabla entries y qualifications, gracias y un saludo

Comment: Ya he conseguido solucionarlo, muchisimas gracias

Comment: Genial, ¿qué era? Así dejamos la pregunta cerrada

Comment: Simplemente estaba confundiendo dos campos y estaba mezclando los nombre de los campos con las tablas